# ViewMasterPage - what is MVC 3's Razor Equivalent?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm converting MVC 2 over to MVC 3, and I have a custom class that inherits from System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage for my Default.Master file.

When converting over to MVC 3, I still want to have a custom class for my Layout.cshtml file, but what should I inherit from?  I'm looking for something like System.Web.Mvc.ViewLayoutPage and System.Web.Mvc.ViewLayoutPage<>, but they do not exist.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalent. Master pages in Razor are simple `.cshtml` files. In fact there is no distinction between a view and a layout. Both are simple `.cshtml` templates. It's only the `~/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml` file which specifies which layout to be used by default. Obviously you could always create a custom layout template in the `~/Views/Shared` folder and then specify it either in the `~/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml` or override it in each specific view or also in the controller action when returning a view you have the possibility of specifying a master page.

For more information about Razor views you may checkout the [following blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx).

Comment: but, if I wanted to have a custom class that I inherit from, say, CustomLayoutPage.cs, and if I wanted to access "this.ViewData.GetValue(...)", how would I do that?  With MVC 2, it was simply inheriting from System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage

Comment: @Ian Davis, you simply [inherit from WebViewPage](http://develoq.net/2011/how-to-change-base-type-of-razor-view-engine-pages/).